# How to troubleshoot high cpu problems related to postgres and postmaster service?

Tags: cpu, ram

I'm using an open source(RHCE 6.2) based machine running SIEM software , when i do the top command i see

> postgress
>   postmaster

both eating 96% of cpu usage? Is there a way to pin-point or see what causing these service to stack up?

thanks.

Comment: @hmayag thanks for pointing me to a direction. Queries makes sense its all about log management so lots of it.

Answer (score 2):

This situation arises when you are running some seriously computationally heavy and complex queries against your database or you have a very high load of queries. Postgres has a few monitoring tools available, one of which is pg_top. Take a look [here](http://ptop.projects.pgfoundry.org)